# Looping over lines with Python

Tags: python, loops

So I have a file that contains this:

```
SequenceName 4.6e-38 810..924
SequenceName_FGS_810..924 VAWNCRQNVFWAPLFQGPYTPARYYYAPEEPKHYQEMKQCFSQTYHGMSFCDGCQIGMCH
SequenceName 1.6e-38 887..992
SequenceName_GYQ_887..992 PLFQGPYTPARYYYAPEEPKHYQEMKQCFSQTYHGMSFCDGCQIGMCH
```

I want my program to read only the lines that contain these protein sequences. Up until now I got this, which skips the first line and read the second one:

```
handle = open(filename, "r")
handle.readline()
linearr = handle.readline().split()
handle.close()

fnamealpha = fname + ".txt"
handle = open(fnamealpha, "w")
handle.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (linearr[0], linearr[1]))
handle.close()
```

But it only processes the first sequence and I need it to process every line that contains a sequence, so I need a loop, how can I do it?
The part that saves to a txt file is really important too so I need to find a way in which I can combine these two objectives.
My output with the above code is:

```
>SequenceName_810..924
VAWNCRQNVFWAPLFQGPYTPARYYYAPEEPKHYQEMKQCFSQTYHGMSFCDGCQIGMCH
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand your question--you want to iterate over the lines in the file, right? But only the second line in the sequence--the one with the protein sequence--matters, correct? Here's my suggestion:

```
# context manager `with` takes care of file closing, error handling
with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('SequenceName_'):
             print line.split()
             # Write to file, etc.
```

My reasoning being that you're only interested in lines that start with `SequenceName_###`.

Comment: "readlines" is evil ! It will allocate an array of lines in memory. Use generators like readline instead. In case of computational biology like this seems the case this is particularly important.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comments on the other answers and read up on the matter. It does indeed seem like readlines is evil, or at least superfluous. I'll edit my answer, thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, on the same note use "xrange" instead of "range", as "range" does allocate a full array in memory, while "xrange" is just the generator version.

Comment: I thought that `readlines`, like `range`, had been converted to a generator expression in Python 3, but for the former this is not the case. `xrange` is deprecated in Python 3, by the way.

Comment: Well, The SequenceName includes the name of different proteins so I can't use that method because the name changes. Thanks anyways for the answer! :)

Comment: @John you should edit your question and indicate that specification. btw, answers should be evaluated on the basis of the posted question not on afterthoughs-born requirements or hidden specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use `readlines` and throw it all into a `for` loop.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines:
        # do processing here
```

In the `#do processing here` section, you can just prepare another list of lines to write to the other file. (Using `with` handles all the proper closure and sure.)

Comment: How does this advice help him skip every other line? Also, the code is wrong. That's not how you call `readlines`, nor is calling `readlines` necessary.

Comment: From what I read, he wants it to skip lines with a particular sequence. For that, he can put the logic in the `for` loop. Also, yes, it is how you call `readlines`. It needs to be attached to a file handle. See: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readlines

Comment: calling "readlines" will create an array of all lines in the file. If the file is big this can be a problem, it is better to use a generator.

Comment: You didn't _call_ readlines at all -- that would be `fh.readlines()`. And it's not necessary because iterating over the file object itself, as in the other answer, yields the lines of the file.

Comment: If size is an issue, you can use the `sizehint` argument for it. I've been able to process log files for clients that are several gigs in size without issues. But, you're right. If it's a big file, it shouldn't be used straight out of the box.

Comment: Syntactical error, sorry. And, yes, you can iterate over the lines of a file using the file object. But, using `with` does all the cleanup automatically. I guess it's just my preferred method.

Comment: It says TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable :(